# Refresh Div only no scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've been trying to refresh a certain div tag only I tried AJAX but I can't use that because there is no source file to pull fro it is pulling it from a database program(the data that needs to be refreshed) I need some code to refresh like when pushing the refresh button but only for certain div id. Can anyone thing of anything?

I tried this, but like I said there is no file is there a name that I can enter in the area where the html file goes that refreshes the page?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval( function refresh()
{
$('#drawaddrow').fadeOut('slow').load('0355.htm').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1500);
</script>
```

I also tried

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshPage () {
            var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop; 
        window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y;

        }
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(refreshPage, 1500);
            if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1 ) {
                var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&")[0].split("=");
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[1];

            }
        }
    </script>
```

but that refreshes the whole page I just need a div id refreshed. Without scrolling to the top!

Comment: I think you need to try AJAX again.  You need a mediator script that does the back-end work as well.  That file that you say "is no file" is what you need to write to make AJAX work

Comment: But there is no html file it is refreshing from. The page is a visual browser representation of data from a software program that runs mathematical equations for titration processes to find concentrations of the bath. The page I'm trying to refresh shows the data from the tests and when the next test is due, hence the refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, this will solve your problem ([source](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

> $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

Let's say you only have 'a.html' and the id of your div is 'divId', you would need to place in your refresh() function:

```
$('#divId').load('a.html #divId');
```

**EDIT**

the code then should be (placed javascript functions inside the div and changed 'refresh' function):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { 
            background-image: url('../Images/Black-BackGround.gif');
            background-repeat: repeat;
        }
        body td {
           font-Family: Arial; 
           font-size: 12px; 
        }
        #Nav a { 
            position:relative; 
            display:block; 
            text-decoration: none; 
            color:black; 
        }
    </style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval( function refresh()
{
$('#toptable').load('0355.htm #toptable'); 
}, 1500);
</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="toptable" align="center">

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="../Images/jsdate.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">function Jump(s){ window.location.href = s ;}</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Date Difference
    //====================================================================================================================

function GetDiff (dt) { 
    sMins = " Min";
    sHours = " Hrs";
    sDays = " Days";
    sSecs = " Secs";

    if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("s", now, dt)) < 86400 ) {
        if ( Math.abs (DateDiff ("s", now, dt)) <= 3600 ) {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs (DateDiff ("s", now, dt)/60)*100)/100).toFixed(2) + sMins);
        }
        else
        {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs (DateDiff ("s", now, dt)/3600)*100)/100).toFixed(2) + sHours);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            return ((Math.floor(Math.abs (DateDiff ("s", now, dt)/86400)*100)/100).toFixed(2) + sDays);
    }
}
    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Function Draw Row
    //====================================================================================================================

</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function DrawRow ( link,Status,Value,ResultName,DateTime,LSL,OPT,USL,LCL,UCL,LO1L,UO1L,LO2L,UO2L,CpK,CP,PPK,PP,TestDue,TestLate,ExpNeeded,ExpLate,AddsNeeded,AddsLate,Count,ActiveCount,Dummy1,ReviewedBy,TestID,ItemID,Dummy2,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,T1,T2,S ) {
    s = "#008A00";
    now = new Date();

    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Color Coding For Results
    //====================================================================================================================

    if ( (Number (Status) & 1073741824) > 0 ) { 
        s = "#C0C0C0";
        a = "center";
        h = "22";
        cr = "#000000";
        sz = "2";


    }
    else
    {

        a = "left";
        h = "22";
        sz = "1";
        cr = "#000000";
        if ( DateDiff ("n", DateTime, "01/01/1980 00:00") == 0 ) { 
            Value = "Not-Tested";       
            DateTime = "Not Tested";
            ResultName = ResultName + " - Needs To Be Tested";
        }
    }

    if (( Number(Status) & 4) > 0 ) { s = "#0000FF"; cr = "#FFFFFF"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 32) > 0 ) { s = "#52CC29"; cr = "#000000"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 16) > 0 ) { s = "#FF4D94"; cr = "#000000"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 2) > 0 ) { s = "#FFFF00"; cr = "#000000"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 1) > 0 ) { s = "#E80000"; cr = "#FFFF00"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 8) > 0 ) { s = "#FF6600"; cr = "#000000"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 0) > 0 ) { s = "008A00"; cr = "#000000"; }





    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Test Status Timing
    //====================================================================================================================

    ReviewIcon = "<p align='center' width='20' height='21'><font size='1'>&nbsp;</font>";   
    Dummy2 = "<b><p align='center' width='20' height='21'><font size='1'>&nbsp;</font></b>";
    if ( Number(ActiveCount) != -1 ) {
        sz = "1";
        a = "left";
        h = "22";
        if ( TestDue > "" && TestLate > "" ) {
            duedif = DateDiff ("s", TestDue, now);
            if ( DateDiff ("s", TestDue, now) >= 0.0 ) { ReviewIcon = "<img  src='../Images/Green-Test.png' width='20' height='21'>"; Dummy2 ="<strong><font size='"+sz+"' color = "+cr+">Due In " + GetDiff (TestLate);}

            else
            {
                duedif = Math.abs (duedif);
                if ( duedif < 3600 ) { duestg = String(Number(Math.floor((duedif/60)*100)/100).toFixed(2)) + " Min"; }
                if (( duedif < 86400 ) && ( duedif >= 3600 )) { duestg = String(Number(Math.floor((duedif/3600)*100)/100).toFixed(2)) + " Hrs"; }
                if ( duedif >= 86400 ) { duestg = String(Number(Math.floor((duedif/86400)*100)/100).toFixed(2)) + " Days"; }
                Dummy2= "<p align='center' width='20' height='22'><b><font size='1' color = "+cr+">Start In " + duestg + "</font></b>";
                ReviewIcon="<img  src='../Images/Blue-Test.png' width='20' height='21'>";
            }

        }
        if ( TestLate > "" ) {
            if ( DateDiff ("s", TestLate, now) >= 0 ) { ReviewIcon = "<img  src='../Images/Red-Test.png' width='20' height='21'>"; Dummy2 = "<strong><font size='1' color = "+cr+">Late By " + GetDiff (TestLate);}             
        }
        if ( TestDue <="" ) {ReviewIcon="<img  src='../Images/Not-Scheduled.png' width='20' height='21'>"; Dummy2 = "<b><font size='"+sz+"' color = "+cr+">Not Scheduled";
    }
        if ( Number(ActiveCount) < Number(Count) ) {ReviewIcon= "<img  src='../Images/GrayAstris.png' width='20' height='21'>"; Dummy12 = "<strong><font size='"+sz+"' color = "+cr+">Deactivated";

        }
    }

    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Date-Time Format
    //====================================================================================================================

    fmtDateTime = DateTime;
    if ( IsDate(DateTime) ) { 
        mnth = DatePart ("m", DateTime); 
        dy = DatePart ("d", DateTime);
        yr = DatePart ("yyyy", DateTime);   // full four-digit year
        yr2 = DatePart ("yyyy", DateTime)-2000;     //should provide last two-digits of year
        hrs = DatePart ("h", DateTime);
        mn = DatePart ("n", DateTime);
        sc = DatePart ("ss", DateTime);

        if ( mnth.toString().length == 1 ) { mnth = "0" + mnth; }
        if ( dy.toString().length == 1 ) { dy = "0" + dy; }
        if ( mn.toString().length == 1 ) { mn = "0" + mn; }

        ampm = "am";
        //bug#604
        if ( Number(hrs) >= 12 ) { 
            ampm = "pm";
            if (Number(hrs) >= 13) {
                hrs = String(Number(hrs) - 12); 
            }
        }

        fmtDateTime = (String(mnth) + "/" + String(dy) + "/" + String(yr2) + "  " + String(hrs) + ":" + String(mn) + " " + String(ampm));       

    }
    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Draw Result Name 
    //====================================================================================================================

    document.write( "<tr bgcolor='"+s+"' height='"+h+"' >" );
    document.write( "<td bg color='#000000' width='2%' height='21' >"+ReviewIcon+"</td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='134' height='22'><p align='center'><b>"+Dummy2+"</b></font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='55'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+Value+"</font></td>");
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='243'><p align='"+a+"'><strong><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ResultName+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='100'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+ fmtDateTime +"</strong></font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='52'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+LSL+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='52'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+OPT+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='52'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+USL+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='54'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+LCL+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='54'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+UCL+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='56'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+CpK+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );

    document.write( "</tr>" );
}

    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Function Draw Add Row
    //====================================================================================================================

 function DrawAddRow ( link,Status,Action,Amount,Unit,Consumable,DueBy,TestReportID,Dummy1,SignedOff,TestID,ItemID,Dummy2,DateTme ) {
    if ( SignedOff == 0 ) { 
        s = "#008A00"; 
        cr = "#000000";
        sz = "2";

        if ( (Number(Status) & 1073741824) > 0 ){ 
            s = "#C0C0C0";
            a = "center";
            h = "22";
            cr = "#000000";
            SignOffIcon = "&nbsp;";


        }
        else

    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Add Status
    //====================================================================================================================

        {
            a = "left";
            h = "18";
            sz = "1";
            if ( DueBy > "" ) {
                if ( DateDiff("n", now, DueBy) >= 0 ) { s = "#008A00"; cr="#000000"; Dummy2 = "<b><font size='"+sz+"' color = "+cr+">Due In " + GetDiff (DueBy); Dummy1 = "<img  src='../Images/Green-Test2.png' width='20' height='18'>";}
            if ( DueBy > "" ) {
                if ( DateDiff("n", DueBy, now) >= 0 ) { s = "#E80000"; cr="#FFFF00"; Dummy2 = "<b><font size='"+sz+"' color = "+cr+">Late By " + GetDiff (DueBy); Dummy1 = "<img  src='../Images/Red-Test2.png' width='20' height='18'>";}

            }
        }
        }


    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Draw Add Row
    //====================================================================================================================

        document.write( "<tr bgcolor='"+s+"' height='"+h+"' >" );
            document.write( "<td width='2%' ><p align='center'><B><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+Dummy1+"</td>" );
        document.write( "<td width='16%' ><p align='center'><B><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+Dummy2+"</td>" );
        document.write( "<td width=32%'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+Consumable+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>" );
        document.write( "<td width='9%'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+Action+"</font></td>");
        document.write( "<td width='10%'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+Amount+"</font></td>");
        document.write( "<td width='7%'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+Unit+"</font></td>" );
        document.write( "<td width='13%'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+DueBy+"</font></td>" );
        document.write( "<td width='10%'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>"+TestReportID+"</font></td>" );
        document.write( "</tr>" );
    }
    }


function DrawRow2 ( link,Status,Value,ResultName,DateTime,LSL,OPT,USL,LCL,UCL,LO1L,UO1L,LO2L,UO2L,CpK,CP,PPK,PP,TestDue,TestLate,ExpNeeded,ExpLate,AddsNeeded,AddsLate,Count,ActiveCount,Dummy1,ReviewedBy,TestID,ItemID,Dummy2,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,T1,T2,S ) {
    s = "#008A00";
    now = new Date();



    //====================================================================================================================
    //          Color Coding For Results
    //====================================================================================================================

    if ( (Number (Status) & 1073741824) > 0 ) { 
        s = "#C0C0C0";
        a = "center";
        h = "22";
        cr = "#000000";
        sz = "2";


    }
    else
    {

        a = "left";
        h = "22";
        sz = "1";
        cr = "#000000";
        if ( DateDiff ("n", DateTime, "01/01/1980 00:00") == 0 ) { 
            Value = "<img  src='../Images/Not-Tested.png' width='53' height='23'>";     
            DateTime = "Not Tested";
            ResultName = ResultName + " - Needs To Be Tested";
        }
    }

    if (( Number(Status) & 2) > 0 ) { s = "#FFFF00"; cr = "#000000"; }
    if (( Number(Status) & 1) > 0 ) { s = "#E80000"; cr = "#FFFF00"; TestIcon = "FFFF00" }


    document.write( "<tr bgcolor='"+s+"' height='"+h+"' >" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='245'><p align='"+a+"'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ResultName+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='50'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+L01L+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='50'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+L01U+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='50'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+PpK+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='50'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+PpK+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='52'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+Pp+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );
    document.write( "<td "+link+" width='52'><p align='center'><b><font size='"+sz+"' color='"+cr+"'>&nbsp;"+Cp+"&nbsp;</font></td>" );

    document.write( "</tr>" );
    }


</script>

<table border="0" width="850" id="Nav" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
<tr>
<td stylE="float:none; height:60; width:850px; align:center;">

    <TABLE style="float:left;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;">
<TR Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;"> <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH>              <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</TH> </TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</TD></TR>



</TABLE>
<div align="center">
   <img style="float:none; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:17px; border:10px ridge #E80000; width:199; height:101;"src="../Images/Logo.jpg" />

<TABLE style="float:right;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;">
<TR Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;"> <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</TH><TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</TD><TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</TD><TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD><TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD></TR>
<TR> <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</TD><TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD></TR>

</td>
</tr>
</div>
<div id="description>
        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="height:5px; text-align:center;"></td></tr>
        </table>

        <table style="border-style:none; width:850px: height:73px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
                <tr>
                <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; height:20px; text-align:center; font-face:arial; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;">IEC's TrueLogic Dashboard</td>
                </tr>
</div>
<div id="group">
        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="height:4px; text-align:center;"></td></tr>
        </table>


                    <table style="border-style:none; width:850px: height:73px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
                        <td style="height:20px; text-align:center;"></td>
                            <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; height:24px; text-align:center; font-face:arial; font-size:20px; font-weight:normal;">[GroupName]</td>
</div>
<div id="object">

        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="height:4px; text-align:center;"></td></tr>
        </table>


    <table style="border-style:none; width:850px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top;">
    <td style="float:left;width:5;"><a href=[BackLink]><img border="0" src="../Images/Back-ButtonB.gif" width="80" height="18"></td>
    <TD style="text-align:center; background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; height:20px; font-face:arial; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">[ObjectName]</td>
    <td style="width:26px;">
    </table>
</div>
<div id="drawrow" align="center">
<table>
<tr><td style="height:8px;"></td></tr>

</table>

        <TABLE style="float:center;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; width:850px; height:18px; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;" table border="1">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            DrawRow ("","1073741824","<b>Value</B>","<b>Result Name</b>","<b>Date - Time</b>","<b>LSL</b>","<b>Opt.</b>","<b>USL</b>","<b>LCL</b>","<b>UCL</b>","<b>LO1L</b>","<b>UO1L</b>","<b>LO2L</b>","<b>UO2L</b>","<b>CpK</b>","Cp","<b>Ppk</b>","<b>PP</b>","<b>ItemID</b>","Dummy1","Dummy2","Dummy3","Dummy4","Dummy5",1,-1,"Dummy6",1,0,0,"Dummy7");
            [ItemsHTML]</script>
        </table>

 <table>

    <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>

 </table>


        <TABLE style="float:center;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; width:850px; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;" table border="1">
            <div id="addrow"><script type="text/javascript">
            DrawAddRow ("","1073741824","Action","Amount","Units","Chemical Additive","Due By","Report ID","","","0","0","Due Status");
            [AddItemsHTML]</script></div>
        </table>

<table>

    <tr><td style="height:20px;"></td></tr>

</table>



<table>

    <tr><td style="height:10px;"></td></tr>

</table>



 <table>


    <tr><td style="height:5px;"></td></tr>


</table>
</div>


<div id="signoff" align="center">
<table style="border-style:none; width:850px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top;">

    <td style="height:25px;">
        <table style="border-style:none; width:850px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00;bwidth:335px; text-align:left; font-size:10;">By TrueLogic Company Edited By International  Electronic Components</td>
                <td width="290"></td>
                <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; bwidth:135px; text-align:right; font-size:10;">[LastBuild]</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


<tr><td style="height:25px;"></td>
</td>
</div>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but there is no html file to get the data from. so a.html doesn't exist. I guess i'm confused to what you're saying

Comment: what file or url contains the data that you want to load into de div?

Comment: I can't refresh the whole page the images flash when I do that if its not scrolled to the top, however if its not scrolled to the top I need it to not scroll to the top. does that make sense. Someone told me ajax would work but its not loaded from an htm file, the time is refreshed from a database from a piece of software..

Comment: @chrisw.iec Ajax indeed does not flash images nor scrolls the page to the top. But it needs a file to load. If you want the same page you are in to be loaded (like you implied by saying "_...like when you hit the refresh button_"), just pass ajax it's name. So, if you are in abc.html, call `$('#divId').load('abc.html #divId');` and it will reload only the div with id="divId".

Comment: and you are sure that performs the exact same function as hitting the refresh button except only for the div id specified because I added the fade in fade out to see if I had the code right and the div id fades in and out but the time does not change like when you hit the refresh button if you look at my code is there something wrong with the refresh but not the fade in and out I have it loading the page it gets the info from?

Comment: this function loads the entire page again behind the scenes, crop the loaded page so that only the content of that div remains and then replace the content of the div with the new one. Basically, it only refresh the inside of the div. The rest remains unchanged.

Comment: That's so bizarre because it doesn't load the new time it only fades in and out the divid i'm trying to load, however when I hit the reload button or use the script I posted second in my question it refreshes the time like i'd expect. Is there anyway to do it without calling it to load a certain .html?

Comment: The data is pulled from the database software program like this `<script type="text/javascript">DrawAddRow ("","1073741824","Action","Amount","Units","Chemical Additive","Due By","Report ID","","","0","0","Due Status");
    [AddItemsHTML]</script>` notice the additems in brakets that's how the data is refreshed yet there is no source file for this

Comment: hummm so you pull the data with javascript. Place this javascript code inside the div tag that you are reloading. It should work. If you want more help, edit your question and place all the code of your html page.

Comment: anyway to help me out?