# Auto Refresh No Scroll Best way to do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

So i'm asking this question again because no one has been able to figure it out. I need to refresh a certain part of my page every few seconds I've tried ajax, but because it requires .load and then the script file that doesn't work, because the refresh is not changing the time till a test is due on the sections I need refreshed. The data is coming from an access database and being displayed in a browser. The database is made and changed by a piece of software that records chemical concentrations of plating baths by mathematical equations yuou program into the software, you can setup schedules that need to be followed fpr these tests. The web browsers then displays this info. So far I can only get the whole page to refresh with no scroll to top with this code.
**Auto Refresh No Scroll Below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshpage () {
        var page_y = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop; 
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?page_y=' + page_y;} 

   window.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(refreshpage, 1500);
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('page_y') != -1 ) {
            var match = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split("&")[0].split("=");
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop = match[1];

        }
    }
</script>
```

I've tried Ajax with fade in and fade out to see if its working but the time does not update like the code anove this.
**Ajax Code to refresh Div ID Below**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{

        $('#drawrow').fadeOut('slow').load('ObjectShellHTML.htm').fadeIn("slow");

}, 9000); 
</script>
```

The info comes out of the database with this script focus on the brackets. [ItemsHTML] seems to grab the data while the draw row draws the columns above the data. I need the info in the brackets refreshed only. But only refreshes with the IE refresh button or the auto refresh no scroll script from the top

```
<div id="drawrow"><script type="text/javascript">
            DrawRow ("",Dummy1","Dummy2","Dummy3","Dummy4","Dummy5",1,-1,"Dummy6",1,0,0,"Dummy7");
            [ItemsHTML]</script></div>
```

I have div tags for the section I need refreshed but like I said there is no source file to load the data with .load. Is there any other way to refresh data like pushing the refresh button on I
E or using the first script I posted, but only focusing the refresh on the drawrow part of the page? The main reason for this is there are a lot of images and the refresh with no scroll seems to flash if the page is not scrolled to the top big problem refreshing every 1.2 seconds which is what i'm trying to accomplish. I've tried using the source file im writing in to load for .load that doesn't work either. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Come on, you asked that only 16 hours ago. You should be more patient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refresh Div only no scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841053/refresh-div-only-no-scroll)

Comment: Anyway, try to simplify the question, reading this is sooooo boring that you will be lucky if someone answers you.

Comment: Be more patient no one answers at all after 18 hours no one even responds to the comments after that!

Comment: @alvaro no if I shorten the example and question everyone assumes ajax is the answer as you see above I've asked a similar question before.

Comment: if you want to refresh only a part of the page, you need to have a way to get just that portion of data from the source.  How is the data getting from Access to html?

Comment: @chrisw.iec ajax is gonna be your answer yes or yest :)

Comment: @Geoff [ItemsHTML] is somehow pulling the data. See last code posted.

Comment: 'how' exactly is the data from Access made into html?

Comment: @alavaro hahaha Thanks. I appreciate that. but unless I can do it without .load that just wont work. there is no source file to use or that can be created because the program wont recognize and update. From the source file the program creates a bunch of out files that are updated every so often in a folder called out when you open the browser these files are accessed yet the source files build each out file.

Comment: @Geoff From a source file ObjectShellHTML.htm but if I try to use that in .load it doesn't update the time counting down, because the source file you are viewing is an out file... you can't put the out file sayO355 because there are 355 different files in a different folder called out, when using ajax on the auto refresh no scroll code I posted or by hitting the refresh button.

Comment: @chrisw.iec, again, if you want to refresh just one part of the page, you need a way to have a source file that has only the content you want to refresh.  otherwise your only choice is to refresh the entire page.

Comment: Let me explain the software has a option where you choose the source files and output files. The source files build the browser representation of the software. The out files are each different tank and plating line. So the out files are built exactly from the source file, but instead of [ItemsHTML] it shows all the chemical names with their concentrations and the time till the test is due when viewing the out files with notepad. so the source file and one out file are exactly the same except depending on the tank you've chosen instead of [ItemsHTML] being there the tank data is there.

Comment: @Geoff `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    window.onload = startInterval;
    function startInterval() {
        setInterval("startTime();", 5000);
    }

    function startTime() {
        document.getElementById('drawrow').innerHTML = ('drawrow');
    }
</script>` you can't do something like this, don't know what to put after the = sign?

Comment: or would creating iframes work any better than div id's?

Comment: @chrisw.iec - so, you have a 'template' file and some process periodically creates several 'out' files based on the template with the most recent data. It is one of the 'out' files you are viewing in the browser.  You want to have javascript periodically reload not the entire 'out' file, but just the changed data after a new 'out' file is created.  Is that all correct?

Comment: @Geoff I don't know because it seems by hitting the refresh button and by using just a meta tag refresh the time changes but with the ajax it just seems there is no time being updated, so i'm not sure. Ye I guess i'll try anything.  Here is the http for the browser file:///C:/Program%20Files/TrueChem/Data/dashboard/out/O355.HTM?page_y=377 but it will be different for each process line and tank in that line there are over 400 O1-O429.htm files. Each would need to access its specific file somehow.

Comment: @chrisw.iec is my paraphrasing of your question right or not?

Comment: Yes your paraphrasing is correct

Comment: @Geoff I don't want the data changed when a new out file is created. with normal refresh the time till something is due counts down, with ajax calling on the template script it does not. I just need the times to change with countdown and I don't think a new out file is created every second as the time changes.

Comment: @Geoff Have you given this anymore thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can use ajax but I cannot select the div from the page I want to load. I can only insert the whole html from a page into the div I select. However there is a memory leak I can't figure out???

```
    loc = window.location.pathname; //grabs page url
pagediv1 = "#pageBody";
pathName = loc.substring(48, loc.lastIndexOf('.') + 4); //parses out url except for htm file name
setTimeout (function() {  

    $(pagediv1).load(pathName, null, function() { 

                });
     },3000);
```